# How to check checkbox while putting it in Array Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, arrays

how would we  put checked checkbox in array as shown in my code,

```
 var idArray = [];
        $("#controls input:checkbox").each(function() {
            idArray.push(this.name);
        });
```

hopes for your suggestion

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a nicer fashion...

```
var idArray = $("#controls input[type='checkbox']")
               .filter(function() { return this.checked; })
               .map(function() { return this.name; })
               .get();
```

I also swapped your selector for one that can handed directly off to `document.querySelectorAll()`, which will increase performance.

Comment: its getting all checkbox not checked once

Comment: @SyedRaza Sorry, try it again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   var idArray = [];
    $("#controls input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('checked'))
        idArray.push($(this).attr('name'));
    });
```

**EDIT:For checked checkboxes**

Answer (score 0):

```
    var idArray = [];
    $("#controls input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        idArray.push(this.name);
    });
```

if you are looking for cheched checkboxes only, you need to add the `:checked` selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
var idArray = [];
        $("#controls input:checkbox").find(":checked").each(function() {
            idArray.push(this.name);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
var idArray = [];
    $("#controls :checked").each(function() {
        idArray.push($(this).attr('name'));
    });
```